# iOS app build shows up under "Activity" but not under "App Store"

Tags: ios, build, submit, app-store-connect

I submitted build 2 of my iOS app to iTunes Connect 9 hours ago.  It's showing up under "Activity" but not under "App Store". There's also no + sign by "Build" on the App Store page, so I don't see any way to add the new build. How can I submit this build?

All that comes up when I click the + by "New Version or Platform" is the opportunity to add tvOS.

This is my first app, so hopefully there's something simple that I'm missing.

[image: actvity]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you add a new version by clicking "(+) Version or Platform" ?

Comment: All that seems to want to do is let me add a tvOS version.  (See added picture above.)

Answer (score 1):

This problem drove me nuts.

Here is what I did not realize: In the App Store section, you can only have a single build in the list at any given time.  Before you are able to select build 2, you have to first delete build 1.

Solution:

- Go to the App Store section under "1.0 Developer Rejected"
- Scroll down to builds and hover your mouse over the "1.0(1)" build
- A red icon with a minus sign will appear
- click this red icon to delete the first build from the list
- now you will be given the option to select a different build